# ElementNotAvailableException thrown in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

Sometimes, in my WPF app, I've got an exception that kills my app.
This exception is `ElementNotAvailableException`.

I searched over internet, but found nothing that can help me.

This error appears sometimes when we switch tab in our application. We cannot reproduce the error every time.

Does someone have any information about this exception?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Are you using try/catches in your application?  You shouldn't have an exception that totally kills the application.

Comment: There is no class `ThrowElementNotAvailableException` in the .net framework. Did you mean `ElementNotAvailableException`?

Comment: Yes this is ElementNotAvailableException, sorry

Comment: I have a handler on UnhandledException on my App. But the code don't pass into that handler ... strange

Comment: Post the code of your `UnhandledException` handler and the StackTrace of the `ElementNotAvailableException`. Do you use UI automation?